# Adding a tab in Blazor server app overrides the data sources (and names) from all previous tabs

Tags: tabs, blazor

I'm still new to this, so pardon me if there's an obvious answer.

I have created a tabbed interface with an interesting flaw. Clicking on button 1 creates a tab with the correct DxDataGrid and tab name, but when button 2 is clicked, the newly created tab 2 **and tab 1** show the data and tab name that apply to button 2. The same thing happens if I click the buttons in the opposite order, and the same behavior occurs upon subsequent button clicks.

This behavior may be related: when you create tab 1, the grid loads immediately, but you must click each tab (after tab two's creation) in order to get them to load.

```
<DxMenuItem Text="Button 1" Click='() => AddNewTab("Grid1")' />
<DxMenuItem Text="Button 2" Click='() => AddNewTab("Grid2")' />

<DxTabs RenderMode="TabsRenderMode.OnDemand">
    @for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        @switch (caseStmtTabName[tdiIndex])
        {
            case "Grid1":
                @renderGrid1BrowsePage(tdiIndex)
                break;
            case "Grid2":
                @renderGrid2BrowsePage(tdiIndex)
                break;
        }
    }
</DxTabs>

@code

int tdiIndex = 0;
int count = 0;
string[] caseStmtTabName = new string[99];

public void AddNewTab(string tabName)
{
    tdiIndex++;
    caseStmtTabName[tdiIndex] = tabName;
    count++;
}

    private RenderFragment renderGrid1BrowsePage(int index)
{
    RenderFragment grid1Item = grid1TabChildContent =>
    {
        grid1TabChildContent.OpenComponent<DxTabPage>(0);
        grid1TabChildContent.AddAttribute(1, "Text", "Grid1");
        grid1TabChildContent.AddAttribute(2, "ActiveTabIndex", index);
        grid1TabChildContent.AddAttribute(3, "ChildContent", (RenderFragment)((grid1TabPageChildContent) =>
        {
            grid1TabPageChildContent.OpenComponent<Grid1>(0);
            grid1TabPageChildContent.CloseComponent();
        }));
        grid1TabChildContent.CloseComponent();
    };
    //tdiIndex++;
    return grid1Item;
}

    private RenderFragment renderGrid2BrowsePage(int index)
{
    RenderFragment grid2Item = grid2TabChildContent =>
    {
        grid2TabChildContent.OpenComponent<DxTabPage>(0);
        grid2TabChildContent.AddAttribute(1, "Text", "Grdi2");
        grid2TabChildContent.AddAttribute(2, "ActiveTabIndex", index);
        grid2TabChildContent.AddAttribute(3, "ChildContent", (RenderFragment)((grid2TabPageChildContent) =>
        {
            grid2TabPageChildContent.OpenComponent<Grid2>(0);
            grid2TabPageChildContent.CloseComponent();
        }));
        grid2TabChildContent.CloseComponent();
    };
    //tdiIndex++;
    return grid2Item;
}
```

I understand that rewriting the "renderGridPages" for each button is WET, but passing a string into the data type will be another task for another day (along with a few other things above).

Thanks for any advice you have!

Comment: The RenderFragment receives a aprameter `index` that it never uses.

Comment: Index gets applied to ActiveTabIndex.

Comment: No, `"index"` is not `index` . Your TabIndex gets a string.

Comment: Right you are! However, removing the quotes does not change the behavior.

Comment: After the second click tdiIndex is updated this causes a re-render. The loop is executed the passed value of tdiIndex will be the same for both iterations. Your code is working as expected.

Comment: The `for(i)` loop does not use `i`. You will show the same tabs `count` times.

Comment: @BrianParker - I ran a watch on caseStmtTabName[tdiIndex] and caseStmtTabName. The different names are preserved in the array, while the current value is in the string. I thought the array would keep each tab in order. Was I mistaken?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I substituted i for the renderGridBrowsePage parameter which I believe was where you were pointing me, but I get the same result. At any rate, my intention was to use i solely to execute the for loop after count gets incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is behaving as you've coded it.

Click on button 1 and you increment `tdiIndex` to 1 and add "Grid1" to caseStmtTabName at index 1.  You display one tab.

Click on button 2 and you increment `tdiIndex` to 2 and add `Grid2` to caseStmtTabName at index 2.

Now look at you loop code:

```
@switch (caseStmtTabName[tdiIndex])
```

At this point `tdiIndex` is 2 for both loop iterations and thus `caseStmtTabName[tdiIndex]` returns "Grid2" and thus

```
  case "Grid2":
    @renderGrid2BrowsePage(tdiIndex)
    break;
```

gets called both times.  Exactly what I believe you see.

I don't use DevExpress so can't produce an exact answer.  Here's a  generic version of your code using standard Blazor components and Bootstrap to demonstrate the techniques you can use.

```cs
@page "/"

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => AddTab(1)">Add Grid 1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="() => AddTab(2)">Add Grid 2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" @onclick="() => AddTab(3)">Add Grid 3</button>
</div>

<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    @foreach (var tab in this.displayTabs)
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link @this.ActiveTab(tab) hand" aria-current="page" @onclick="() => SetActiveContent(tab)">@tab.Name</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>

@foreach (var tab in this.displayTabs)
{
    <div @key="tab" class="@this.ShowTab(tab)">
        @tab.Content
    </div>
}
<style>
    .show-content {
        display: block;
    }

    .hide-content {
        display: none;
    }

    .hand {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

@code {
    class Tab
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public RenderFragment? Content { get; set; }
    }

    List<Tab> tabs = new();

    IEnumerable<Tab> displayTabs => this.tabs.OrderBy(item => item.Id);

    int activeTabIndex;

    string ActiveTab(Tab tab)
        => GetActiveIndex() == tab.Id ? "active" : string.Empty;

    string ShowTab(Tab tab)
        => GetActiveIndex() == tab.Id ? "show-content" : "hide-content";

    void SetActiveContent(Tab tab)
        => activeTabIndex = tab.Id;

    int GetActiveIndex()
    {
        if (tabs.Any(item => item.Id == activeTabIndex))
            return activeTabIndex;
        if (tabs.Count > 0)
            return tabs[0].Id;
        return 0;
    }

    void AddTab(int index)
    {
        if (tabs.Any(item => item.Id == index))
        {
            tabs.Remove(tabs.First(item => item.Id == index));
            return;
        }
        tabs.Add(new Tab()
            {
                Id = index,
                Name = $"Grid {index}",
                Content = (builder) =>
                {
                    builder.AddMarkupContent(0, $"<div>Hello {index}</div>");
                }
            });
        activeTabIndex = index;
    }
}
```